# why does socket in a service become null when app pauses or stops?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a simple app that uses a socket connection for p2p communication through a service. It is my understanding that a service will continue to run and needs to be stopped when the the app is destroyed. However, when my app pauses or stops, (ie activity not visible) the socket in the server becomes null and the app crashes.

Here is the method in my activity that starts the service.

```
public void startServerService(){

    //if (!serverThreadActive) {
        serverServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ServerService.class);

        //serverServiceIntent.putExtra("GoAddress", goAddress);
        serverServiceIntent.putExtra("GOPort", prefixedPort);
        serverServiceIntent.putExtra("Result", new ResultReceiver(null){

            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, final Bundle resultData) {

                //String message = resultData.getString("msg");
                //addLine(message);   //back from ServerService with mssg so add to textview line 181
                final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rcvd);
                tv.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv.append("\n" + (String)resultData.get("msg"));
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        serverThreadActive = true;
        startService(serverServiceIntent);
}
```

An here is the service itself.

```
   public class ServerService extends IntentService{

    //DECLARATIONS
    private boolean serviceEnabled;
    private int mGoPort = 8080;
    private String message;
    private ResultReceiver serverResult;
    private InetAddress mGoAddress;
    private ServerSocket mServerSocket;
    private Thread mServerThread;


    public ServerService(){
        super("ServerService");
        serviceEnabled =  true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //mGoPort = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get("GOPort");
        //mGoAddress = (InetAddress)intent.getExtras().get("GOAddress");
        serverResult = (ResultReceiver)intent.getExtras().get("Result");

        mServerThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        mServerThread.start();
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Socket socket;

            try {
                mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(mGoPort);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                try {
                    socket = mServerSocket.accept();            //THIS SOCKET IS NULL AFTER APP
                                                                //STOP AND RESTART
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable{

        private Socket clientSocket;
        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket){
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                        (this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                try {
                    String read = input.readLine();
                    updateMessages(read, false);
                    //input.close();                  //TRY TO FIX CRASH
                    //clientSocket.close();           //ADDED TO TRY TO FIX CRASH
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void updateMessages(String msg, boolean local){

        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        if (local) {
            msg = "me: " + msg;
        }
        else{
            msg = "them: " + msg;
        }

        Bundle messageBundle = new Bundle();
        messageBundle.putString("msg", msg);

        serverResult.send(mGoPort, messageBundle);
    }
}
```

When the app is paused or stopped, like when the home button on the device is pushed, the variable mServerSocket becomes null

```
socket = mServerSocket.accept();            //THIS SOCKET IS NULL AFTER APP
                                            //STOPS AND RESTARTS
```

How do I fix this so that the communication ability remains functional after the
activity pauses and restarts or stops and restarts?

Thank you for any ideas, hints or clues.

Oh, and here's the manifest part

```
<service android:name=".ServerService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"/>
```

Another update - even a socket waiting in onHandleIntent still becomes null after the main activity pauses.

Comment: It is intentservice, your understanding is wrong... It spawning it's own thread and you should only do the stuff inside onHandleIntent.

Comment: Where is `mServerSocket` defined?

Comment: @Selvin - Thank you. I kind of have an idea what you mean by that. Will report back after changes.

Comment: @EJP - Sorry about that. I cut off the first part with the declarations